# Sum from JSON fields in MySQL

Tags: mysql, arrays, json, sum

here is a short batch of records from MySQL 8 with a JSON field

```
id, cmd_json, reg_day
(
    1,
    '[
        {"id": 1, "qty": 1, "tax": 2, "ref": "art 1", "price": 100},
        {"id": 2, "qty": 1, "tax": 1, "ref": "art 2", "price": 10}
    ]',
    '2019-10-29'
),
(
    2,
    '[
        {"id": 1, "qty": 1, "tax": 2, "ref": "art 3", "price": 12}
    ]',
    '2019-10-29'
);
```

I want to have the sums of the records with tax 1 and tax 2

Here is my approach, but the result is wrong

```
$q_t1s = Model::where('reg_day', $date)->where('cmd_json', 'like', '%"tax": 1%')->get();
$sumT1 = 0;
foreach ($q_t1s as $q_t1):
    $t1s = $q_t1->cmd_json;
    foreach ($t1s as $t1):
        $sumT1 += ($t1['qty'] * $t1['price']);
    endforeach;
endforeach;
dd($sumT1);
```

I code with Laravel 6

If you can help me find the solution, thank you

Comment: Are you possibly looking for a MySQL solution with this? It should be possible to write a SQL query that does the computation.

Comment: Also please show us your expected results.

Comment: $sumT1 give 110. I'm starting to see clearly, but it remains confusing for me...

Answer (score 0):

In MySQL 8.0, it possible to do the computation directly in the database. Here is a raw SQL query for that purpose:

```
select tax, sum(price) total_price
from 
    mytable t,
    json_table(
        cmd_json,
        "$[*]"
        columns(
            id int path "$.id",
            qty int path "$.qty",
            tax int path "$.tax",
            ref varchar(10) path "$.ref",
            price int path "$.price"
        )
    ) d
group by tax
```

This works by transforming the json arrays into rows, using json function `json_table()` (available since MySQL 8.0), then aggregating the results. This will return one record for each distinct value of `tax`, along with the total of related `price`s.

This **[demo on DB Fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=b324c1f3517fcf9349278f6ee30125ac)** with your sample data returns:

```
tax | total_price
--: | ----------:
  2 |         112
  1 |          10
```

Answer (score 0):

So I found a solution, certainly not the prettiest, but it works.

Thank's GMB for your MySQL solution, but I don't know how to integrate it in Laravel :/

```
$req_days = Model::where('reg_day', $date)->get();

if (count($req_days) > 0):
    $sum_tax_1 = 0;
    $sum_tax_2 = 0;
    foreach ($req_days as $req_day):
        $req_taxs = $req_day->cmd_json;
        foreach ($req_taxs as $req_tax):
            if ($req_tax['tax'] === 1):
                $sum_tax_1 += ($req_tax['qty'] * $req_tax['price']);
            elseif($req_tax['tax'] === 2):
                $sum_tax_2 += ($req_tax['qty'] * $req_tax['price']);
            endif;
        endforeach;
    endforeach;
    dd($sum_tax_1, $sum_tax_2);
    // RESULTS ARE OK
else:
    $noCash = '<h1 class="text-center text-warning">No cash this day</h1>';
endif;
```